# ElasticSearch docker "HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests" after 360k documents

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying ElasticSearch 7.9 and wanted to do a benchmark on 1M documents. I use the 'single node' docker image.

I use the high level java client to index documents using `BulkRequest`. I consistenly get a `Too Many Requests` exception after 360k requests, even if I put some `sleep(1000)` statements after each `10k` docs.

I tried increasing the memory in the `jvm.options` from `1G` to `8G` but that did not affect it.

Is there an option to increase this number of requests?

My laptop has 4 cores and 16GB and docker is not limited in any way.

Error details:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"es_rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=0, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=0, coordinating_operation_bytes=108400734, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=107374182]"}],"type":"es_rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=0, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=0, coordinating_operation_bytes=108400734, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=107374182]"},"status":429}
```

### Indexing code

```
            CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(index);
            createIndexRequest.mapping(
                    "{\n" +
                            "  \"properties\": {\n" +
                            "    \"category\": {\n" +
                            "      \"type\": \"keyword\"\n" +
                            "    },\n" +
                            "    \"title\": {\n" +
                            "      \"type\": \"keyword\"\n" +
                            "    },\n" +
                            "    \"naam\": {\n" +
                            "      \"type\": \"keyword\"\n" +
                            "    }\n" +
                            "  }\n" +
                            "}",
                    XContentType.JSON);
            CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

            for (int b=0;b<100; b++) {
                List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
                    int item = b*100_000 + i;
                    bookList.add(new Book("" + item,
                            item % 2 == 0 ? "aap" : "banaan",
                            item % 4 == 0 ? "naam1" : "naam2",
                            "Rob" + item,
                            "The great start" + item/100,
                            item));
                }
                bookList.forEach(book -> {
                    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest().
                            source(objectMapper.convertValue(book, Map.class)).index(index).id(book.id());
                    bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
                });
                System.out.println("Ok, batch: " + b);
                bulkRequest.timeout(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(20));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1_000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    client.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
                    System.out.println("Ok2");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
//            System.out.println(objectMapper.convertValue(book, Map.class));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. I just kept adding request to the `BulkRequest` instead of clearing it.